# Why my answer has to be deleted?

Tags: discussion

I have posted an answer here [Magento question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265130/magento-api-request-foreach-error).
Why Amit Bera deleted my answer?
Although it has almost the same answer with the other answer, my answer is more detailed and more precise according to what the questions need. I'm just so disappointed. I give time and effort to provide solution with the question it just happened that the other guy was able to post his answer earlier than mine.
I have tested my answer and provided it believing that it will help the one asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magefms, Mistakenly your answer is deleted by me. Now it is undeleted.

Comment: Thank you much for that Amit.